# Error: cannot convert in simple std::string file slurper

Tags: c++, file, scripting, ifstream, sstream

I'm using some fairly simple C++ code to slurp the contents of a file into a `std::string`:

```
// Read contents of file given to a std::string.
std::string f = "main.js";
std::ifstream ifs(f.c_str());
std::stringstream sstr;
sstr << ifs.rdbuf();
std::string code = sstr.str();
```

But when I compile, I get this error:

```
error: could not convert ‘((*(const std::allocator<char>*)(& std::allocator<char>())),
(operator new(4u), (<statement>, ((std::string*)<anonymous>))))’ from ‘std::string*
{aka std::basic_string<char>*}’ to ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’
```

I know this is probably a simple mistake but I'm still very much learning C++. Should just be a simple type mixup or something.

On request, here is some example code of what I'm trying to do:

```
std::string Slurp(std::string f)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(f.c_str());
    std::stringstream sstr;
    sstr << ifs.rdbuf();
    std::string code = sstr.str();
    return code;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't create objects using `new` in C++ unless you want dynamic allocation. `new` returns a pointer. This should work.

```
std::string f("main.js");
std::ifstream ifs(f.c_str());
```

The constructor of `std::ifstream` expects a `const char *` so you need to use `std::string::c_str()`

Comment: `f` actually represents a `std::string` that was an argument to a function with my slurp code. I still get the error with `c_str()`.

Comment: Your code compiles properly for me. Have you included all the headers? Check [here](http://ideone.com/7FQvSX)

Comment: Ah, I've found it. I was passing a pointer as an argument to the slurp function.